# find minimum even number from a list in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Please help me write a function in haskell which would help me find a minimum even number in a list. Incase the list contains all the odd number throw an exception. I am able to write two separate functions but not able to write one complete program. My code is as follows.

```
retainEven :: [Int] -> [Int]
retainEven [] = []
retainEven (n:ns)= 

    if ((mod n 2) == 0)
        then n : (retainEven ns) 
    else retainEven ns


enter code here




mymin [] = error "no element" 
mymin [x] = x  
mymin (x:y:xs) = mymin ((if x < y then x else y):xs)
```

Comment: Hint: use functions `minimum` and `filter`.

Answer (score 3):

Filter for elements that are even and then take the minimum:

```
minEvens = minimum . filter even
```

Comment: Can you write it in as a user defined function ?

Comment: It is a user defined function! If you want it to use the functions you defined, it's `minEvens = mymin . retainEven`.

Comment: You can look at the implementation for minimum, filter and even if you want.